# How to pass knitr dev.args in yaml (quarto document)

Tags: r, knitr, quarto

I want to pass a list as `dev.args` chunk option to knitr in the yaml header of a Quarto document.

According to the documentation it is possible to pass chunk options to knitr in the yaml header. For example:

```
---
title: "My Document"
format: html
knitr:
  opts_chunk: 
    collapse: true
    comment: "#>" 
---
```

I want to pass a list to dev.args. I tried

```
knitr:
  opts_chunk: 
    dev.args: list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

with or without quotes, nothing works.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

- `dev.args` are arguments for the graphics device that generates plots, usually, that is `png()`. Look at `?png` to see available arguments. Most device arguments in Quarto are already set by other (implicit) chunk or document-wide options, and you'll get an error when you try to set i.e. width or height this way.
- Quarto YAML headers can not process R code. Use YAML key/value pairs instead. In the example below, we set the `bg` argument of the png device to yellow and the `type` to cairo.

````
---
format: html
knitr:
  opts_chunk: 
    dev.args:
      bg: yellow
      type: cairo
---

```{r}
plot(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Till answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207441/how-to-pass-knitr-dev-args-in-yaml-quarto-document/77209418#77209418) pointed me the right direction, although for **pdf** output it needs a little tweak:

````
---
format: pdf
knitr:
  opts_chunk: 
    dev.args:
      pdf:
        bg: yellow
---

```{r}
plot(mtcars)
```
````

As [Till answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207441/how-to-pass-knitr-dev-args-in-yaml-quarto-document/77209418#77209418) also mentions, any attempt to change options that are set somewhere else will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for me in a slight variant of this .

```
format:   
  revealjs:
    default-image-extension: png
execute: 
  message: false
  warning: false
  echo: false
  dev.args:
      bg: transparent # plot backgrounds
```